# Is my comma usage correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, commas

I have this sentence but I'm not sure if my comma usage was correct

> In the final lines, he writes, “save outrage for something even more monstrous – the way we are contributing to the starvation of children and exacerbating the world’s worst humanitarian crisis.”

Answer (score 1):

You don't need commas there.

You could place a comma after the word "lines" to separate the prepositional phrase "in the final lines" from the rest of the sentence. But you should not place a comma after the verb "writes" and the quotation.

As written it looks like "he writes" is a parenthetical phrase which could be omitted.  I would not use either comma here.